# Google Play application compatibility

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play

I have a problem whith my application on Google Play. In fact my app it's not compatible with custom rom like miui, custom Ics... 
For example I can't download my app from google play with my GS2 on miui and my friend can download it with is GS2 on ICS.
Please help me...

here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.notifyme"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<supports-screens 
 android:largeScreens="true" 
 android:normalScreens="true" 
 android:smallScreens="true" 
 android:anyDensity="true" /> 

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  />

<permission android:name="com.notifyme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.notifyme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SOUND" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LIGHTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/notifme_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >


    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ConnexionActivity" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".InscriptionActivity" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <receiver
        android:name=".ReceiverActivity"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
         <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" > </action>
            <category android:name="com.notifyme" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" ></action>
            <category android:name="com.notifyme" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
</application>
```

thank you

Comment: The problem for this is going to be in your manifest file, please can you post up the code you have for your manifest? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that the problem lay withing your code. One of your activities might has a method that is supported only since API 13 (e.g. Android 3.2 and above). That's why it can be downloaded for newer version (ICS which is android 4) and not your. 
double check your methods to figure that out.